# ADO SQL modifies data on other tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ado

i´ve been trying to update some record using a form that has a couple of comboboxes in it and those are populated from auxiliary tables that contains city and department (the table that needs to be updated only holds the ID from both "side" tables.

Since i was having some hard times to insert the data directly i decided to use ADO for direct SQL Insert.

So far my VBA code looks like this:

```
Private Sub btnClose_Click()
    Dim Msg, Style, Title, Ctxt, Help, Response, MyString

    Msg = "Want to save changes?"
    Style = vbYesNo + vbQuestion
    Tytle = "Confirm changes"
    Ctxt = 1000

    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Tytle, Help, Ctxt)

    If Response = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    Else
        Call ManualUpdate
    End If
End Sub
```

And the ManualUpdate sub:

```
Private Sub ManualUpdate()
    Dim ccnDb As ADODB.Connection
    Set ccnDb = CurrentProject.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "UPDATE personal SET personaApPaterno = " & "'" & Trim(Me.personaApPaterno.Value) & "'"
    strSQL = strSQL & ", personaApMaterno = " & "'" & Trim(Me.personaApMaterno.Value) & "'"
    strSQL = strSQL & ", personaNombre = " & "'" & Trim(Me.personaNombre.Value) & "'"
    strSQL = strSQL & ", personaCargo = " & "'" & Trim(Me.personaCargo.Value) & "'"
    strSQL = strSQL & ", departamentoId = " & Me.cmbDepto.Value
    strSQL = strSQL & ", ciudadId = " & Me.cmbCiudad.Value
    strSQL = strSQL & ", personaProfesion = " & "'" & Trim(Me.personaProfesion.Value) & "'"
    strSQL = strSQL & ", personaGerente = " & Me.personaGerente.Value
    strSQL = strSQL & ", personaExterno = " & Me.personaExterno.Value
    strSQL = strSQL & ", personaSexo = " & Me.ogSexo.Value
    strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE personaRUT = " & Me.personaRUT.Value

    If Me.Dirty Then
        Me.Dirty = False
    End If

    With cmd
        .CommandText = strSQL
        .ActiveConnection = ccnDb
        .Execute
    End With

    Set cmd = Nothing
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

So far... so good...

As you can see the SQL does a DIRECT upgrade to the table called "personal", and is working fine, the ONLY thing that is driving me crazy is that, for some odd reason, Access 2007 is updating the auxiliary tables and replacing the text at the "ciudadName" and "departamentoName" fields with their own respective Id´s. Just for some extra information, i was using DAO before ADO.

Here is the DAO code also...

```
Private Sub ManualUpdate()
    Dim dbDao As DAO.Database
    Dim rsDao As DAO.Recordset

    If Me.Dirty Then
        Me.Dirty = False
    End If

    Set dbDao = CurrentDb
    Set rsDao = dbDao.OpenRecordset("personal", dbOpenTable)

    rsDao.FindFirst ("personaRUT = " & Me.personaRUT.Value)
    rsDao.Edit

    rsDao![personaApPaterno] = Trim(Me.personaApPaterno.Value)
    rsDao![personaApMaterno] = Trim(Me.personaApMaterno.Value)
    rsDao![personaNombre] = Trim(Me.personaNombre.Value)
    rsDao![personaCargo] = Me.personaCargo.Value
    rsDao![departamentoId] = Me.cmbDepto.Value
    rsDao![comunaId] = Me.cmbComuna.Value
    rsDao![personaProfesion] = Me.personaProfesion.Value
    rsDao![personaGerente] = Me.personaGerente.Value
    rsDao![personaExterno] = Me.personaExterno.Value
    rsDao![personaSexo] = Me.ogSexo.Value

    rsDao.Update

    rsDao.Close
    dbDao.Close

    Set dbDao = Nothing
    Set rsDao = Nothing
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

BTW: DAO was doin THE same "update" where it was not supposed to be happening, that why i went for the ADO way, but with no luck at all.

EDIT:

Decided to add some extra information that i consider to be relevant in order to get the correct help for my issue. The idea is to show how the different tables are related to each other.

[image: This is the relevant part of the Schema for the Database i´m having issues with...]

If needed i can also upload a capture of the form it self.

Comment: Perhaps your relationships are configured incorrectly... Just a guess.

Comment: Another possibility is the combo boxes are bound to your "side" (I call them lookup) tables in such a way that selecting the combo box updates the lookup table.

Comment: That sounds like something to check... any way, for what i understand i´m supposed to have those lookup in a pre-built query (view) and do a SELECT DISTINCT on the Lookup ID's?

Comment: Nope.. it  just keeps updating, but i do noticed something, when i load the "personal" editing form i notice that as soon as i click on the combobox that contains the departamentoId + descDepartamento it will update the field "descDepartamento" to it´s corresponding "departamentoId" at the "departamentos" table.. the funny thing.. i don´t have a single line that calls for an explicit update (all the events for this combobox holds no VBA at all).

Answer (score 0):

Check combobox Data. ControlSource property is blank.